# How build httpstatus on linux by dotnet core 3?

Tags: c#, .net

httpstatus is Easily generate different HTTP responses for testing

Repository https://github.com/Readify/httpstatus

```
dotnet --version
3.0.100
```

Cd src in repo httpstatus

```
ls
Teapot.sln  Teapot.Web
Build:
```

dotnet build

```
/root/httpstatus/src/Teapot.Web/Teapot.Web.csproj(145,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.100/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v16.0/WebApplications/Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Build FAILED.

/root/httpstatus/src/Teapot.Web/Teapot.Web.csproj(145,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.100/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v16.0/WebApplications/Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

Comment: There is some issue with the references containing that class. Maybe they moved, or maybe the Compiler lacks read rights on the folders? You could try sudo to check for the rights thing.

Comment: I see that you (or a like-minded individual) filed an issue on GitHub, which sounds like a better fit for this problem than SO.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that this is not an ASP.NET Core web project, and cannot be built on this platform (Linux?). To build such project, you would need a Windows box, and two things:

- MSBuild (this is incorporated in the dotnet installation as well)
- the corresponding SDK - in your case, the [workload](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/visual-studio-workloads/) for building web projects.

You can install this workload, named "**ASP.NET and web development**", using [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/) or [Build Tools for Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019) installers.